# Upgrade to Kubuntu 18.04 from Kubuntu 17.10

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

Running Kubuntu 17.10.

And wanted to upgrade to Kubuntu 18.04.

But [on this website,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BionicUpgrades/Kubuntu) it says:

> Note: Upgrades from 17.10 will not be enabled until a few days after
>   18.04's release. Upgrades from 16.04 LTS may not be enabled until a few days after the 18.04.1 release expected in late July.

This is pretty vague --- 'until a few days' part.

So, can I upgrade now?

Comment: @karel No. My question is not a duplicate of the question you have mentioned. I am not upgrading from one LTS to the next. I am upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04

Comment: I know that. It still works even when upgrading from a non-LTS to a non-LTS release. It works anyway. By default upgrades to an LTS release are automatically suppressed until the first point release, but you can change it from the default settings to upgrade immediately.

Comment: @karel Thanks. But my question is specifically about 'until a few days' part. Are those 'a few days' over? Can I upgrade now?

Comment: I upgraded to 18.04 a few hours after it was released on April 26. After upgrading I used `apt autoremove` and `deborphan` to remove obsolete packages from the previous version.

Comment: @karel Thanks. I will also try it out now. But I wonder why do they put that notice on the Kubuntu website? That too, the text is highlighted, etc. :)

Comment: Waiting for the first point release gives Canonical a margin of time to fix bugs in the initial LTS release before pushing it to all systems as an upgrade.